# Excel - Vlookup from multiselect Data validation list

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Good afternoon,

I have the below code, which allows for the multiple selection of items within a single data validation list, what i need is a vlookup that can find each item in the drop down list and return the corresponding values.

For example, i have all the data being used for the vlookup on sheet 2, when i select from the drop down list C0, XS 100, NCD - i want the vlookup to go to sheet 2, find C0, XS 100 & NCD and return the values for each item (the return values is text that the user needs to read)

I dont know if im barking up the wrong tree here and if this is even possible but any help would be greatly received

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Destination As Range)
  Dim rngDropdown As Range
  Dim oldValue As String
  Dim newValue As String
  Dim DelimiterType As String
  DelimiterType = " | "
  Dim DelimiterCount As Integer
  Dim TargetType As Integer
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim arr() As String
  
  If Destination.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  On Error Resume Next
  
  Set rngDropdown = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
  On Error GoTo exitError
  
  If rngDropdown Is Nothing Then GoTo exitError
  
  If Not Intersect(Destination, Range("C25")) Is Nothing Then
    TargetType = 0
    TargetType = Destination.Validation.Type
    If TargetType = 3 Then  ' is validation type is "list"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        newValue = Destination.Value
        Application.Undo
        oldValue = Destination.Value
        Destination.Value = newValue
        If oldValue <> "" Then
            If newValue <> "" Then
                If oldValue = newValue Or oldValue = newValue & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "") Or oldValue = newValue & DelimiterType Then ' leave the value if there is only one in the list
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, DelimiterType, "")
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "")
                    Destination.Value = oldValue
                ElseIf InStr(1, oldValue, DelimiterType & newValue) Then
                    arr = Split(oldValue, DelimiterType)
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(newValue, arr, 0)) = 0 Then
                    Destination.Value = oldValue & DelimiterType & newValue
                        Else:
                    Destination.Value = ""
                    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
                    If arr(i) <> newValue Then
                        Destination.Value = Destination.Value & arr(i) & DelimiterType
                    End If
                    Next i
                Destination.Value = Left(Destination.Value, Len(Destination.Value) - Len(DelimiterType))
                End If
                ElseIf InStr(1, oldValue, newValue & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) Then
                    oldValue = Replace(oldValue, newValue, "")
                    Destination.Value = oldValue
                Else
                    Destination.Value = oldValue & DelimiterType & newValue
                End If
                Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "") & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) ' remove extra commas and spaces
                Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType & Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""))
                If Destination.Value <> "" Then
                    If Right(Destination.Value, 2) = DelimiterType Then  ' remove delimiter at the end
                        Destination.Value = Left(Destination.Value, Len(Destination.Value) - 2)
                    End If
                End If
                If InStr(1, Destination.Value, DelimiterType) = 1 Then ' remove delimiter as first characters
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType, "", 1, 1)
                End If
                If InStr(1, Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) = 1 Then
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "", 1, 1)
                End If
                DelimiterCount = 0
                For i = 1 To Len(Destination.Value)
                    If InStr(i, Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", "")) Then
                        DelimiterCount = DelimiterCount + 1
                    End If
                Next i
                If DelimiterCount = 1 Then ' remove delimiter if last character
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, DelimiterType, "")
                    Destination.Value = Replace(Destination.Value, Replace(DelimiterType, " ", ""), "")
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
  End If
 
  If Not Intersect(Destination, Range("C7")) Is Nothing Then
      Select Case Destination
          Case Is = "Solutions"
              MsgBox "YOU HAVE SELECTED: SOLUTIONS POLICY - NO NCD CHECK REQUIRED"
          Case Is = "H/Sol"
              MsgBox "YOU HAVE SELECTED HEALTHIER SOLUTIONS POLICY - CHECK THE NCD IN UNO AND ACPM"
         End Select
  End If
             
        If Not Intersect(Destination, Range("G7")) Is Nothing Then
      Select Case Destination
          Case Is = "NMORI"
              MsgBox "NMORI - FULL HISTORY TO BE TAKEN - USE STEP 2 TO HELP YOU DETERMINE IF THE SYMPTOMS ARE PRE-EXISTING"
          Case Is = "CMORI"
              MsgBox "CMORI - FULL HISTORY TO BE TAKEN - USE STEP 2 TO HELP YOU DETERMINE IF THE SYMPTOMS ARE PRE-EXISTING"
          Case Is = "CME"
              MsgBox "CME - CHECK IF THE SYMPTOMS ARE RELATED TO ANY EXCLUSIONS IF NOT RELATED TREAT AS MHD"
          Case Is = "FMU"
              MsgBox "FMU - CHECK HISTORY, CHECK IF SYMPTOMS ARE RELATED TO ANY EXCLUSIONS & CHECK IF THE SYMPTOMS REPORTED SHOULD HAVE BEEN DELCARED TO US"
          Case Is = "MHD"
        
              MsgBox "MHD - TAKE BRIEF HISTORY ONLY"
End Select
End If

exitError:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

As im not massively VBA experienced and have essentially relied upon others for help. The only thing i have tried is a this =Vlookup(C25, C26, C27,Sheet2!A1:B21,2,0) but this returns a spill error and doesnt really work well from a user view and also isnt asesthetically pleasing

Comment: You'd need to write a UDF in VBA which splits the multi-valued cell into individual values, and then performs a vlookup for each of the values.  You've not told us where the results should go (all in one cell, or into multiple cells?) so it's difficult to offer much more here.

Comment: The results will all go into one cell so it can be read like reading a book page.

Comment: Some specific cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: handling multiple drop-downs and combining lookups into a single textbox

Try this out:

```vb
Option Explicit

Const DELIM As String = " | "

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim oldValue As String, newValue As String, sep As String
    Dim arr() As String, s As String, el, remove As Boolean, allDDVals As String
    
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    newValue = Target.Value
    
    On Error GoTo exitError
    
    Select Case Target.Address(False, False)
        Case "C25", "C26", "C27", "C28" '<<< 4 potential drop-downs
            If Not HasListValidation(Target) Then Exit Sub
            If Len(newValue) > 0 Then 'check cell was not cleared
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Application.Undo
                oldValue = Target.Value
                If Len(oldValue) > 0 Then
                    arr = Split(oldValue, DELIM)
                    For Each el In arr
                        If el = newValue Then
                            remove = True 'remove if re-selected
                        Else
                            s = s & sep & el 'else add to cell content
                            sep = DELIM
                        End If
                    Next el
                    If Not remove Then s = s & sep & newValue 'add if not a re-selection
                    Target.Value = s
                Else
                    Target.Value = newValue
                End If
            End If
            allDDVals = MultiLookup(Me.Range("C25").Value, Me.Range("C26").Value, _
                                    Me.Range("C27").Value, Me.Range("C28").Value)
            Me.Range("D25").Value = allDDVals 'perform the lookups and populate (eg) to the next cell
            Me.OLEObjects("Textbox1").Object.Value = allDDVals 'or add to textbox
        Case "C7"
            Select Case newValue
                Case "Solutions"
                    MsgBox "YOU HAVE SELECTED: SOLUTIONS POLICY - NO NCD CHECK REQUIRED"
                Case "H/Sol"
                    MsgBox "YOU HAVE SELECTED HEALTHIER SOLUTIONS POLICY - CHECK THE NCD IN UNO AND ACPM"
            End Select     'C7 values
        Case "G7"
            Select Case newValue
                Case "NMORI", "CMORI"
                    MsgBox newValue & " - FULL HISTORY TO BE TAKEN - USE STEP 2 TO HELP" & _
                                     " YOU DETERMINE IF THE SYMPTOMS ARE PRE-EXISTING"
                Case "CMORI"
                    MsgBox "CMORI - FULL HISTORY TO BE TAKEN - USE STEP 2 TO HELP YOU " & _
                            "DETERMINE IF THE SYMPTOMS ARE PRE-EXISTING"
                Case "CME"
                    MsgBox "CME - CHECK IF THE SYMPTOMS ARE RELATED TO ANY EXCLUSIONS" & _
                           " IF NOT RELATED TREAT AS MHD"
                Case "FMU"
                    MsgBox "FMU - CHECK HISTORY, CHECK IF SYMPTOMS ARE RELATED TO ANY EXCLUSIONS " & _
                           " CHECK IF THE SYMPTOMS REPORTED SHOULD HAVE BEEN DELCARED TO US"
                Case "MHD"
                    MsgBox "MHD - TAKE BRIEF HISTORY ONLY"
            End Select    'G7 values
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
        
    End Select            'Target address
    
exitError:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

'Given input `txt` containing zero or more DELIM-separated values,
'  perform a lookup on each value, and return all of the results in
'  a single string
'  Returns "?value?" for any term not matched in the vlookup
Function MultiLookup(ParamArray texts() As Variant)
    Dim arr, el, s As String, res, sep As String, i As Long, txt As String
    For i = LBound(texts) To UBound(texts)
        txt = texts(i)
        If Len(txt) > 0 Then
            arr = Split(txt, DELIM)
            For Each el In arr
                res = Application.VLookup(el, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B21"), 2, False)
                If IsError(res) Then res = "?" & el & "?"
                s = s & sep & res
                sep = vbLf '## use different delimiter for the output
            Next el
        End If
    Next i
    MultiLookup = s
End Function


'does a cell have list validation applied?
Public Function HasListValidation(c As Range) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no validation on cell
    HasListValidation = (c.Validation.Type = 3)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the above, ive implemented it into VBA editor, and it partially works, howeever when i select the items in Cell C25 the results in cell D25 it doesnt return the lookup result, for example if i select C0 & C2 it returns the value of ?C0C2? instead of the correct result.

Comment: How does the content show up in C25 after selecting C0 and C2?  Did you include the `Const DELIM As String = " | "` ?  C25 should have `C0 | C2`

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for getting back to me, i figured out what the issue was the Delim had spaces either side of the | which was causing it to just show ?C0C2? in the return cell i took the spaces out and it now shows the correct results. One final question[, is it possible to have the results read in paragraphs, so for example, C0 text is read and then there is an empty line and then the next paragraph to be read is then C2. Would that be possible in this code? Thanks again for your help im truly grateful.

Comment: If you swap out DELIM for `vbLf` then you'll have a newline after each value...   Please flag this answer as "Accepted" if it's working for you, to help anyone coming along later with a similar question.

Comment: Tim you are a legend! Thank you so so much for your help on this.

Comment: Hi Tim, 

Ive been given a couple of feedback points for improvement and wondered if you could help at all. 

In the cell that has the Data validation list, when using vblf it puts each selection on a new line, is there any way this can be stopped from happening and the new line requirement be soley for the the cell where the vlookup result populates?

Also is there a way to have the vlookup results populate in an activex textbox with a blank line between each result? 

Thanks in advance

Comment: Switch the global constant DELIM back to `" | "` and then in `MultiLookup` change this line `sep = DELIM` to `sep = vbLf`.  As for the ActiveX thing - that sounds like a different question.

Comment: Added textbox option above....

Comment: Hi Tim, 
I hope this finds you well, thanks for all your help on this project of mine, its been well received by those using it and ive had some feedback that im looking to implement. 

Is it possible with this code you have provided to be able to select choices from 4 individual drop down lists and then the vlookup populates the results into the textbox? 

Im playing around with the idea of having 4 data validation lists to use, when a selection is made from each list, the vlookup returns the value of each choice from the lists into the textbox.

Comment: One textbox per dropdown, or 4 dropdowns all feeding into the same textbox?

Comment: 4 drops into one textbox please Tim

Comment: And is it the same lookup parameters for each of those dropdowns, or does each dropdown have a different lookup table/return column?

Comment: All the same lookup requirements mate all the lookup requirements are on Sheet 2 which will be hidden from users view.

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for providing the above this works perfectly, only one snag, is there a way to have the drop downs list populate without a blank line between each selection within the list?

Comment: Populate where?  In the textbox?  If you're talking about the results from `MultiLookup` then change the line `sep = vbLf` to whatever separator you want.

Comment: Tim, as always youre a legend, thank you very much for you help with this again.